# ctx.Err() vs ctx.Done() chan closed check: Is there a difference?

Tags: go

I am in a long running cancellable function that has a forever-loop.

I need to check if context is closed.

```
go func(){
    for {
         if ctx.Err() != nil { return }
         // do work
    }
}()
```

vs

```
go func(){
    for {
         select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            default:
         }
         // do work
    }
}()
```

Is there a difference between the two?

I am guessing checking ctx.Err() is safe for concurrent-access https://golang.org/src/context/context.go#L370 so they seem identical, given a closed context will always have Err set.

Comment: One lets you select on a channel, and the other doesn't. A context is safe for concurrent use, so there's not much else to it

Comment: If you're checking if the context is cancelled, use `ctx.Done`, which is for checking if the context is cancelled. If you're checking for an error, use `ctx.Err`, which is for checking for an error.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. ctx.Err returns an error for cancelled contexts as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the `context.Context` [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context):

> If Done is not yet closed, Err returns nil.
> If Done is closed, Err returns a non-nil error explaining why

By extension, we can say that your first sample is checking if `Done` is closed. Given the convention for done channels that they should only ever be closed, and never have any values sent on them, we can say that your second sample is also checking if `Done` is closed.

So, we can say that the two code samples are functionally equivalent. The reason why we have different ways to check is because each offers some benefit:

- `Err()` is an immediate check and gives error information.
- `Done()` is a channel, and so can waited on or used in a `select` case.

Comment: `Err()` is also much cheaper.

Comment: @NunoCruces I'm curious, are you able to point us to a benchmark? I ask because `Context` is an interface and can be implemented any number of ways. Looking at `cancelCtx`, for example, `Err` locks and unlocks a mutex every time, whereas `Done` only uses a mutex once. So maybe (in that case) `Err` is only cheaper the first time around?

Comment: The first time around it loads an atomic, locks, reload, creates a channel, stores it, unlocks. Subsequently, yes it loads an atomic, but you get back a channel from it, how do check that it's done? select. How is that cheaper than err != nil?