# Go - Stopping forever for loop with context

Tags: go, channel

I have an async process which should go on forever thats looking like this:

```
func asyncForeverTask() {
  for {
    anyTask()
  }
}

func main() {
  go asyncForeverTask()

  server.run(8080)
}
```

I would like to be able to stop this for loop when a certain request request comes to the server.

I am aware that I need to use the `context.WithCancel()`, but I do not know how to integrate it for it to work. I know the following syntax:

```
for {
  select {
  case <-ctx.Done:
    return
  case <-otherCh:
    // do smh.
  }
}
```

but the `asyncForeverTask` is not run by a signal from any otherCh, but it runs forever. I am a noobie to go and would appreciate any type of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a channel:

```
var stopAsync = make(chan struct{})

func asyncForeverTask() {
  for {
    select {
      case <-stopAsync:
         return
      default:
    }
    anyTask()
  }
}
```

To cancel, simply close the channel. You have to make sure channel is closed only once, otherwise you'll get a panic.

You can also do this with a context:

```
func main() {
   ctx,cancel:=context.WithCancel(context.Background())
   go asyncForeverTask(ctx)
   ...
}

func asyncForeverTask(ctx context.Context) {
  for {
    select {
      case <-ctx.Done():
         return
      default:
    }
    anyTask()
  }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
func asyncForeverTask(ctx context.Context) {
  for {
    if ctx.Err()!=nil {
       return
    }
    anyTask()
  }
```

To stop, call the `cancel` function returned:

```
...
cancel()
```

If you need to stop the `anyTask` as well, you have to check for the channel closure or context closure every so often and return from the task.

Comment: This is great and seems to be working with one small exception to what I need, if the cancel function is called while anyTask is in the middle of the execution (because its a relatively longer task in my specific case). I would like for anyTask to stop proceeding immediately (or at least close to immediately). Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Alternative to the select is `if ctx.Err() != nil {  }` (as per [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/context#Context) "If Done is not yet closed, Err returns nil. If Done is closed, Err returns a non-nil error" - more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67446481/11810946)).

Comment: Thanks @Brits, added this as an option.

Answer (score 2):

Channels and contexts work and can be handy. But they're not your only option. For something like this a simple `atomic.Bool` might be simpler. Something like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

func asyncForeverTask(stop *atomic.Bool) {
    for {
        if stop.Load() {
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("I'm still running")
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    var stop atomic.Bool
    go asyncForeverTask(&stop)
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    stop.Store(true)
}
```

Comment: This answer is great as well. And in case i need to stop the ongoing process by adding multiple checks, this would be much cleaner compared to for-select statements all over the place.

Comment: You can remove multiple select statements with a simple closure, like `canceled() bool`

Comment: @[Oliver Dain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431244/oliver-dain) Having ```main``` and ```asyncForeverTask``` in two different packages produces compilation error ```undefined another_package.asyncForeverTask```

Comment: @vtm11 it's hard to say why you're getting a compilation error without seeing your coffee. But the problem probably isn't really related to this question. I suggest opening a new question specifically about your issue.

Comment: @OliverDain I haven't changed asyncForeverTask to AsyncForeverTask while moving the function to another package. What a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, but this simple closure approach works too:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var done bool = false

func asyncForeverTask() {
    for {
        if done {
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("I'm still running")
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    go asyncForeverTask()
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    done = true
}
```

Yes, I know global variables are evil. Just for a record.

Comment: [The Go Memory Model](https://go.dev/ref/mem) states "Programs that modify data being simultaneously accessed by multiple goroutines must serialize such access". So the behaviour of your app is undefined (it probably works, perhaps on all CPU's, maybe with a delay, and possibly on future Go versions). The [race detector](https://go.dev/blog/race-detector) will detect the issue.